# How to parse [29:00:00 28:30:20 27:10:11 26:00:01 25:00:40] with DateTime C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

Simple Case 1:

inputs:

```
29:00:00 28:30:20 27:10:11 26:00:01 25:00:40 08:11:12 12:10:18 15:05:05
```

outputs:

```
05:00:00 04:30:20 03:10:11 02:00:01 01:00:40 08:11:12 12:10:18 15:05:05
```

My Function that doesn't works:

```
public static DateTime ParseDate(string s)
{
  DateTime result;
  if (!DateTime.TryParse(s, out result))
  {
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "29:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    result = result.AddDays(1);
  }
  return result;
}

ParseDate("27:10:11");
```

get error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What is the data meant to represent? 29:00:00 clearly isn't a date/time value...

Comment: Surely this is a TimeSpan thing?

Comment: I get 29:00:00 etc.. from external api as string i cant change it

Comment: What's the data supposed to represent ? What do you expect as a result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that it's actually a `TimSpan` and you want to return a `DateTime` (`DateTime.Today + timespan`). Note that you cannot create a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) via [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx) or `ParseExact` that is greater than 24 hours. You need to do it in this way:

```
public static DateTime GetAddTimespan(string span)
{
    var tokens = span.Split(':');
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(
                  int.Parse(tokens[0]),    // hours
                  int.Parse(tokens[1]),    // minutes
                  int.Parse(tokens[2]));   // seconds)                              
    return DateTime.Today + ts;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need custom code for this, the DateTime.TryParse is not the right tool. Have a look at timespan. That will solve whatevery you are trying to do. However you still need to check for > 23 on the hour part from .net 4.0 onward.

```
//                     23:0:0        23:00:00 
//                     24:0:0   Parse operation failed.
```

[TimeSpan msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with DateTIme since they are not valid timestamps. You can do something like that with TimeSpan

```
public static DateTime ParseDate(string s)
{
  var tokens = s.Split(':').Select(x => int.Parse(x));
  var now = DateTime.Now;
  return new DateTime(now.Year,
                      now.Month,
                      now.day,
                      tokens[0] % 24,
                      tokens[1],
                      tokens[2]);
}
```

That simply parses the content and ensures that the hour value is between 0 and 23 (both included). There's no errorhandling in the parsing so the input needs to be valid

Since you are looking for a DAteTime value you'd need to supply a date as well as a time of day. The above code assumes that the date should be today and that you can dsregard whether or not the hour value is larger than 23